# What is the process behind the Democratic Iowa Caucus?

Tags: united-states, election, voting, primaries

I've been trying to figure out exactly how the Democratic Caucus in Iowa works for days, but I can't seem to find any sources that lays it all out entirely. I know that there were thousands of delegates that were chosen yesterday, and that these will vote on a county level and then a congressional district level until 48 national delegates are chosen. The part I'm really confused about is how do the votes in precincts convert into the first round of delegates. But I could really do with a complete explanation about how the entire process works, to be honest.

Comment: While a perfectly valid question, this seems to be relatively easily answered via google. I'd start with the wikipedia article on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iowa_caucuses#Democratic_Party_process

Comment: Yes, I've read this. But it's very vague and doesn't go into the details. It barely says anything about the higher level elections. For example, it doesn't say what the difference between a state and district level convention is. How are the districts determined? These are the kinds of things that aren't explained anywhere I've looked.

Answer (score 3):

Several political scientists published a book called "[Why Iowa](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/W/bo10415852.html)?" which described these processes in depth.  Much of the book is available online for free.

[Chapter 3](http://www.whyiowa.org/Why%20Iowa%20Chapter%203.pdf) describes "caucus math" and how delegates are assigned based on precinct results. Delegates are assigned proportionally based on the number who caucus for that candidate in each district, with rounding:

> If in a group of 200 
>   caucusgoers there are 110 for Obama, 50 for Edwards, and 40 for Clinton 
>   once all alignments are made, then Obama will be allocated 55% of that 
>   precinct’s county convention delegates, Edwards 25%, and Clinton 20%. (pg.57)

The caucusgoers elect the individual delegates from among themselves.